# How to create a masked TextBox for taking IP Address input?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a masked TextBox for taking input similar to IP Address. I dont want to use the third party controls and want to develop my own. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

I have managed to restrict the keyboard entry to digits. How do I add the (   .   .   .   ) mask?

Comment: Why don't you want to use third party controls?

Comment: If you want to develop it yourself, so be it... then develop it yourself and come back here with code if you get stuck. Maybe you can get some inspiration out of the 3rd parties tools you don't want to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are very keen to develop your own control for the same. You may have to handle the key event and render the value according to specified mask

here is a similar masked textbox from wpf toolkit

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/MaskedTextBox/Implementation/MaskedTextBox.cs

this link provide complete implementation, you may have a  look and develop your own

Answer (score 4):

****This is the perfect way .**
there is a native Win32 control that supports handling of IP Addresse

```
  public class IPTextBox : TextBox
        {
            public IPTextBox() : base()
            {

            }

            protected override CreateParams CreateParams
            {
                get
                {
                    new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode).Demand();
                    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                    cp.ClassName = "SysIPAddress32";
                    return cp;
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: This example only applies to Windows Forms - the question is about WPF.  Just thought I'd point that out to save other people wasting 20 minutes before realising...

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised there wasn't something recent, or at least halfway decent for Windows Forms in c# that solved this problem even to the point that it could be polished into something maintainable without returning to Windows 3.1 syntax, cmds, msgs, lpcstrs. importing dlls, and such.

I created a control out of 4 textboxes, three bitmaps (dots) MSDN application notes, and some key event handlers. Rejecting non-digits wasn't hard, truncating the text string to three characters in insert mode wasn't hard, but it took a little trial and error to find a combination that allowed smooth transition between the text boxes on enter and tab key presses. It was a little frustrating getting the last text box to transfer focus to the next control in the form.

As always, tab and enter are handled differently, and do things under the covers between key down and keypress - I had to guess at what was happening, since I don't have any fancy step-through source libraries.

Anyway, here's my solution. I wrote it yesterday, and tested it today. I have a demo tomorrow, wish me luck.

```
    using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Framework.UserApplication.Utility;

namespace Framework.UserApplication.CommonDialogs
{
    /**************************************************************************************************
     * A TCP IP input mask.
     * sealed because of virtual member calls in constructor
     *  By having a virtual call in an object's constructor you are introducing the possibility that
     *  inheriting objects will execute code before they have been fully initialized.
     **************************************************************************************************/

    public sealed partial class TcpIpInputMaskType : UserControl
    {
        private bool _hasFocus; // True if this TcpIpInputMaskType has focus

        private IPAddress _ipAddress; // The IP address
        private bool _showFocusRect; // True to show, false to hide the focus rectangle

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Default constructor.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        public TcpIpInputMaskType()
        {
            _showFocusRect = ShowFocusCues;
            _hasFocus = false;
            InitializeComponent();
            ChangeUICues += IpTextBoxes_ChangeUiCues;
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            AutoSize = true;
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Gets the IP address.
         *
         * @return  The IP address.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        public IPAddress IpAddress
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    _ipAddress = new IPAddress(new[]
                    {
                        Convert.ToByte(IP1.Text), Convert.ToByte(IP2.Text),
                        Convert.ToByte(IP3.Text), Convert.ToByte(IP4.Text)
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _ipAddress = null;
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }

                return _ipAddress;
            }
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Gets the IP address hex string.
         *
         * @return  The IP hex address string.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        public string IpAddressHexString
        {
            get
            {
                if (IpAddress == null)
                    return "";

                var barry = new[]
                {
                    Convert.ToByte(IP1.Text),
                    Convert.ToByte(IP2.Text),
                    Convert.ToByte(IP3.Text),
                    Convert.ToByte(IP4.Text)
                };
                return AsciiHexConversionType.ByteArrayToHexWithSpaces(barry);
            }
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Gets the dotted IP address string.
         *
         * @return  The dotted IP address string.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        public string DottedIpAddressString
        {
            get
            {
                if (_ipAddress == null)
                    return "";

                return IpAddress.ToString();
            }
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Gets the ulong IP address.
         *
         * @return  The ulong IP address.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        public ulong UlongIpAddress
        {
            get
            {
                if (IpAddress == null)
                    return 0;

                var address = (ulong) (Convert.ToByte(IP1.Text) * (256 ^ 3)) +
                              (ulong) (Convert.ToByte(IP2.Text) * (256 ^ 2)) +
                              (ulong) (Convert.ToByte(IP3.Text) * 256) + Convert.ToByte(IP4.Text);
                return address;
            }
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Change focus.
         *
         * @param   ipTextBox   The IP control.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        private void ChangeFocus(TextBox ipTextBox)
        {
            switch (ipTextBox.Name)
            {
                case "IP1":
                    IP2.Select();
                    break;
                case "IP2":
                    IP3.Select();
                    break;
                case "IP3":
                    IP4.Select();
                    break;
                case "IP4":
                    ipTextBox.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
                    break;
            }
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Event handler. Called by IP1 for key press events.
         *
         * @param   sender  Source of the event.
         * @param   e       Key press event information.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        private void IP1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            var ipTextBox = sender as TextBox;
            switch (e.KeyChar)
            {
                case '\r':
                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                    e.Handled = true;
                    return;
                case '\t':
                    if (ipTextBox != null)
                        ChangeFocus(ipTextBox);
                    e.Handled = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                        e.Handled = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Event handler. Called by IP1 for text changed events.
         *
         * @param   sender  Source of the event.
         * @param   e       Event information.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        private void IP1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ipTextBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (ipTextBox != null && ipTextBox.TextLength == 4)
            {
                ipTextBox.Text = ipTextBox.Text.Substring(0, 3);
                return;
            }

            if (ipTextBox != null && ipTextBox.TextLength == 3)
                ChangeFocus(ipTextBox);
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Event handler. Called by IP4 for key down events.
         *
         * @param   sender  Source of the event.
         * @param   e       Key event information.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        private void IP4_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Event handler. Called by IpTextBoxes for change user interface cues events.
         *
         * @param   sender  Source of the event.
         * @param   e       User interface cues event information.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        private void IpTextBoxes_ChangeUiCues(object sender, UICuesEventArgs e)
        {
            _showFocusRect = e.ShowFocus;
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Control.Enter" />
         *  event.
         *
         * @param   e   An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs" />
         *               that contains the event data.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Control.Leave" />
         *  event.
         *
         * @param   e   An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs" />
         *               that contains the event data.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Control.LostFocus" />
         *  event.
         *
         * @param   e   An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs" />
         *               that contains the event data.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            _hasFocus = false;
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Control.Paint" />
         *  event.
         *
         * @param   e   A <see cref="T:System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs" />
         *               that contains the event data.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var focusRect = ClientRectangle;
            focusRect.Inflate(-2, -2);
            if (_hasFocus && _showFocusRect)
                ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, focusRect, ForeColor, BackColor);
            else
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(BackColor, 1), focusRect);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        /**************************************************************************************************
         * Sets default IP address.
         *
         * @param   ip1 The first IP.
         * @param   ip2 The second IP.
         * @param   ip3 The third IP.
         * @param   ip4 The fourth IP.
         *
         * @return  The IPAddress.
         **************************************************************************************************/

        public IPAddress SetDefaultIpAddress(string ip1, string ip2, string ip3, string ip4)
        {
            IP1.Text = ip1;
            IP2.Text = ip2;
            IP3.Text = ip3;
            IP4.Text = ip4;
            return IpAddress;
            }
        }

}
```

here's the designer code

```
namespace Framework.UserApplication.CommonDialogs
{
    sealed partial class TcpIpInputMaskType
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.pictureBox5 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.IP2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.IP3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.IP4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.IP1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox5)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox4)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox5
            // 
            this.pictureBox5.Image = global::Framework.Properties.Resources.dot1;
            this.pictureBox5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(87, 26);
            this.pictureBox5.Name = "pictureBox5";
            this.pictureBox5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 5);
            this.pictureBox5.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox5.TabIndex = 91;
            this.pictureBox5.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox4
            // 
            this.pictureBox4.Image = global::Framework.Properties.Resources.dot1;
            this.pictureBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(57, 25);
            this.pictureBox4.Name = "pictureBox4";
            this.pictureBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 5);
            this.pictureBox4.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox4.TabIndex = 90;
            this.pictureBox4.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox3
            // 
            this.pictureBox3.Image = global::Framework.Properties.Resources.dot1;
            this.pictureBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 25);
            this.pictureBox3.Name = "pictureBox3";
            this.pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 5);
            this.pictureBox3.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox3.TabIndex = 89;
            this.pictureBox3.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // IP2
            // 
            this.IP2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(32, 5);
            this.IP2.Name = "IP2";
            this.IP2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 20);
            this.IP2.TabIndex = 86;
            this.IP2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.IP1_TextChanged);
            this.IP2.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.IP1_KeyPress);
            // 
            // IP3
            // 
            this.IP3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(61, 5);
            this.IP3.Name = "IP3";
            this.IP3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 20);
            this.IP3.TabIndex = 87;
            this.IP3.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.IP1_TextChanged);
            this.IP3.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.IP1_KeyPress);
            // 
            // IP4
            // 
            this.IP4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 5);
            this.IP4.Name = "IP4";
            this.IP4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 20);
            this.IP4.TabIndex = 88;
            this.IP4.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.IP1_TextChanged);
            this.IP4.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.IP1_KeyPress);
            // 
            // IP1
            // 
            this.IP1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 5);
            this.IP1.Name = "IP1";
            this.IP1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 20);
            this.IP1.TabIndex = 85;
            this.IP1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.IP1_TextChanged);
            this.IP1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.IP4_KeyDown);
            this.IP1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.IP1_KeyPress);
            // 
            // TcpIpInputMaskType
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.IP2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.IP3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.IP4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.IP1);
            this.Name = "TcpIpInputMaskType";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(126, 31);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox5)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox4)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox IP2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox IP3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox IP4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox IP1;
    }
}
```

here is "dot1" in my project, the background is transparent. It's a little hinky when there's more than one thing behind it, but you can match the color in the designer, no problem.

If I run into anything, I'll come back and edit this post.

[dot1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uoZ6.png)

Answer (score -1):

Windows WPF includes this already. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Imports needed:

```
System.Net.IPAddress
System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
```

Now, you need to set the properties:

```
MaskedTextBox.Mask = ###.###.###.### 
MaskedTextBox.ValidatingType = typeof(System.Net.IPAddress);
```

Comment: Since when WPF includes `MaskedTextBox`? I think you're confusing it with WinForms

Comment: Correct, this is importing the WinForms MaskedTextBox, and it will need to be the child of a WindowsFormsHost object.